# How to draw a best fit mesh on a set of points in 2D

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, mesh, hough-transform

I have a problem where we have a grid of points and I'd like to fit a "deformed grid which would best fit the set of points.

The MatLab data can be found at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14fKKEC5BKGDOjzWupWFSmythqUrRXae4/view?usp=sharing
You will see that cenX and cenY are the x and y coordinates of these centroids.

[image]

Like on this image. To note is that there are points missing, and there are a few extra points. Moreover, You can see some lines are not one single line from left to right, however, we could safely assume that the fitting a line somewhat horizontally (+-5degrees) would properly link the points into a somewhat deformed grid.

The vertical lines are trivial because that is how we generated these dots. We can find the number of lines required through a mode of the count of points on each of the columns of the grid.

I'd like to be able to ensure that a point is only part of one line, as this is a grid.

[image]

Comment: You could take the first column, check for each point the closest point on the few next column where abs(angle) is not bigger than 5°. Then repeat the process for column 2,3,4,....

Comment: How about drawing a rectangular grid and transforming it using opencv `remap` to fit your samples?

Comment: @dhanushka Remap applies a transformation from one image to another and could be used once I have the transformation, but how would I find the transformation in the first place?

Comment: Do you need it for display purpose or do you need it for interpolation? And is it OK if the grid doesn't go through every point as there are noise in the points as well.